# Customer and Partners are not able to login to Service Cloud

Tags: customer-portal, customer-community

Customer and Partners users with profile "HCIT customer community user" are not able to login to Service Cloud, and they are getting error message:"No available community".
All other profiles are able to log-in
What is a possible solution?

Comment: Is that profile set as enabled for the desired community?

Comment: Could you please tell me how to check it ?

Thanks

Comment: @Sanjay N, did the below answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Setup > Customize > community > Select your community Name > now enter admin management > Member > And give access to your profile` there. It will solve your problem.